# Print set characters with string Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, character

In Python 3, how can I set a string to print in a set amount of characters no matter the length, like how you can do `{:6.2f}` for floats.  Set it so that it will take 20 characters, even if there isn't 20 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same way.

```
>>> '{:20}'.format('1234567890')
'1234567890          '
```

If you need to limit the length then specify the precision as well.

```
>>> '{:20}'.format('123456789012345678901234567890')
'123456789012345678901234567890'
>>> '{:20.20}'.format('123456789012345678901234567890')
'12345678901234567890'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use %20s syntax:

```
"%20s" % "12345" # => '               12345'
```

For left justification use %-20s:

```
"%-20s" % "12345" # => '12345               '
```

For limitation string length use %20.20s syntax, where first number is min string length and second number is max.

```
"%20.20s" % ("12345" * 5) # => '12345123451234512345'
```